# Issue while getting data from URL. PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $url = 'https://www.inmateaid.com/prison-search/all?&page=1';
    $output = file_get_contents($url); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($output);
    $selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $anchors = $selector->query("/html/body//div[@class='media']//div/h4//a");
    foreach($anchors as $a)
    { 
        $output = file_get_contents($a->getAttribute("href")); 
        echo 'hi';
    }
?>
```

if we see below code produces 10 anchors

`$anchors = $selector>query("/html/body//div[@class='media']//div/h4//a");`

so how should be printed 10 times? but it only prints for 3 times.

When I comment the line inside for loop, it get hi printed 10 times.

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: I just tried your code, and I got `hi` 10 times, as expected. Is this the actual, full code you're using?

Comment: Yes i got too 10 times 'hi' with the tried code..

Comment: I checked again and surprisingly, this time it is printed 4 times.

Comment: Tried your code and get 'hi' 10 times .

Comment: Turn your error reporting on `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` and see if there are errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was due to `max_execution_time = 30`. I increased the time and issue was fixed.